# Передать данные через сокеты и замерить скорость

Tags: delphi, сокет, клиент-сервер

Стоит задача сделать клиент-серверное приложения на Delphi. Нужно передать любые данные методом `sendbuf`, при этом задать размер буфера.
Также  нужно вывести скорость передачи.
Пока могу только подключить клиент к серверу.

Comment: Откуда такое жесткое условие - `sendbuf`? Это означает - использовать TClient/TServerSocket? Насколько я знаю, только у них есть такой метод.

Comment: да, именно TClient/TServerSocket

Comment: А первая часть уточняющего вопроса? Точно нельзя использовать другие методы этих компонентов?

Comment: задача стоит в том, что бы отправить буфер, при этом указать его размер и измерять скорость передачи. я думаю через _sendbuf_ будет наиболее удобно. но это чисто мое мнение

Comment: Так а что конкретно не получается?